# i want to set an image on fragment A's imageview from fragment B's image position which is a gridview

Tags: android

here i have one Activity in which half of the screen i'm using tabview say A with fragments and in another half screen i'm using another tabview say B with fragments

now i want to set an image on  imageview of tabview A's fragment when we select an image item from tabview
[image]B's fragment which containing gridview with images...

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Looking at the Master/Detail flow template in Android Studio will pretty much cover everything you need to know about moving things from one fragment to another.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxIBG.png

Comment: simply there are 2 fragments are visible on one activity i want to set an image on one fragment's imageview from another fragment's images(gridview of images)onitemClick